# generate line graph from spreadsheet with month and category column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

Trying to generate a line graph that shows the amount a certain category happened per month. The spreadsheet has the category of an instance as well as the month it occurred. Easy way to do this?

E.g.

```
**Month **Event
January Logo
January Wedding
January Save the Date
January Save the Date
January Save the Date
January Crest
January Wedding
January Wedding Save the Date
January Wedding
January Crest for Wedding
January Wedding
January Wedding
January Wedding
January Wedding
January Logo
January Editorial
January Crest
January Wedding
January Wedding
January Wedding
January Wedding
January Calligraphy Commission
January Crest for Wedding
January Crest for Wedding
January Wedding
January Wedding
February    Calligraphy Commission
February    Illustrations
February    Wedding Save the Date
February    Certificate Fill-In
February    High End Party
February    Wedding
February    Editorial
February    High End Party
February    Wedding
February    Wedding
February    Save the Date
February    Wedding
February    Crest for Wedding
February    Wedding
February    Wedding
February    Crest
```

etc.

Comment: Use a PivotTable looking at the `Count` of Event.  Make a PivotChart off of the PivotTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This analysis can be easily completed by using a PivotTable to do the counting and a PivotChart to visualize.

Here is the finished product with data similar to yours.

[image: pivots]

When you set up the PivotTable, you will want to determine the ideal way to do the group of `MONTH` and `EVENT`.  It is possible to get different charts depending on if they are both rows or if one is a column and the other row.  The image above is with both as rows.  The main difference is the coloring of the bars will be different if one of them is on the column.

Play with the arrangement until you find what you like.